# Using MySql.Data in .NET AWS Lambda with D.I

Tags: mysql, .net, aws-lambda, dependency-injection

I'm refactoring a .NET AWS Lambda project with MySql.Data in it for connecting to AWS Aurora. I implemented the DI process and registered MySqlConnection into DI container as Transient and injected it into the DataAccess service.

The registration of MySqlConnection and the DataAccess go something like this:

Startup:

```
services.AddTransient<MySqlConnection>(provider => 
{
    //Get the necessary parameters and build a connection string.

    return new MySqlConnection(connectionString);
});

services.AddSingleton<IDataAccess, DataAccess>();
```

DataAccess:

```
private readonly MySqlConnection _connection;

// inject the MySqlConnection.

async function() 
{
  await _connection.OpenAsync();
  await _connection.DoStuff();
  await _connection.CloseAsync();
}
```

My boss concerned that all of the DB interaction will be going through a single connection that is injected into the DataAccess class and she doesn't want the db to crash because I'm not cleaning up the connections properly.

I have a few questions:

1. I see the old code base has the using statement when it create a new MySqlConnection but I don't see one on the MySql documentation. Do I need the "using" statement when I create a new MySqlConnection?
2. Should I register MySqlConnection as Transient and use DI or simply create a new MySqlConnection instance inside the class that use it?
3. Is the DI of the DB connection going to leave a lot of open connections? Or, on the other extreme, that a single connection is going to slow down the lambda because it used to make numerous connections?

Thank you!

Comment: If you inject the connection as transient it will ALWAYS be a different injection, these will be automatically disposed after your program has left the called function. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38139500/18278998) post for a very clear explanation (it is a bit long but will give you some important info if you end up using transient). You are probably best off using `using` statements to ensure proper disposing of the connections. The second question is more dependant on your personal liking, so I can't give a definitive answer to that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IMO, instead of using DI, you can go with `using` statements. SQL connections will be picked from pool that .NET maintain at application level, and will be returned once connection is closed. Refer this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6765844/1273882) for more detail.

However, connection pooling won't help much in case of AWS Lambda, as entire Lambda compute is destroyed after idle timeout. So it is recommended to use [RDS proxy](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/rds-proxy.html) to avoid connection related issues.

> Using RDS Proxy, you can handle unpredictable surges in database traffic. Otherwise, these surges might cause issues due to oversubscribing connections or creating new connections at a fast rate. RDS Proxy establishes a database connection pool and reuses connections in this pool. This approach avoids the memory and CPU overhead of opening a new database connection each time. To protect the database against oversubscription, you can control the number of database connections that are created.

Also, you can checkout  [RDS Proxy for SQL Server with AWS Lambda and .NET 6](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SeRJzNBbC0c)